# disable submit button until selecting a dropdown option without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown select box with "Select one" as a default option and the View report submit button

```
<select name="time" id="time" required>
 <option value="0" selected>Select one</option>
 <option value="1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="act" value="View Report" disabled>
```

The submit button is disabled until either value 1 or 2 is chosen. How can I do this without using jquery? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you tried?

Comment: @Fusei i tried the if else statement if (time.options.value != "0") then document.getElementbyID("btn").disabled = true. I was setting id="btn" for the submit button

Comment: i also tried if (time.options.length == 0) with the same statement but realized "select one" is a select option already :P

Comment: Sorry. Then you should use addEventListner. Anyway, my code works fine. Thank you for your cooperation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see i add an `addEventListener` to `select`, so when that change the script will check if `value` is different to `0`

```js
const select = document.getElementById('time');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
document.getElementById('time').addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (select.value === '0') {
    submitButton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    submitButton.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<select name="time" id="time" required>
  <option value="0" selected>Select one</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="act" id='submit' value="View Report" disabled>
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! why is it "===" instead of "==" may I ask?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript) :)

Comment: Does anybody have the single Event Listener function? Cause I need to use JQuery V1 and this feature is not supportet in this version.Thanks.

Comment: Open a question @Stan

Answer (score 0):

You can use .prop() method. Good Luck!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    Bottom Nav Bar
    </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <select name="time" id="time" required>
     <option value="0" selected>Select one</option>
     <option value="1" >Value 1</option>
     <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="act" value="View Report" disabled>
    </body>
     <script>
    $("#time").click(function() {
             if($("select").val() == 0)
           $("input").prop( "disabled", true);
            else $("input").prop( "disabled", false);
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) :)

Comment: thank you!! our teacher required us not to use jquery for this exercise. but I will start learning it real soon ;D